# Printk process information

Tags: c, linux-kernel, printk

I have the following module which I tried to print PCB information. However I couldn't figure out the output. It was supposed to print process related data. I appreciate any help.

modpcb.c

```
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/fs_struct.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

void retrieve(struct task_struct *task) {

    struct task_struct *ts = current;
     struct list_head *list;

    if(task->state == 1)
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%s", ts->comm);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%lu", ts->min_flt);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%lu", ts->maj_flt);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%li", ts->utime);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%li", ts->stime);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%d", ts->pid);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%u", ts->flags);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%u", ts->start_time);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Process Name%ld", ts->state);

    list_for_each(list, &current->children) {
        ts = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        retrieve(ts);
    }

}

static int __init pcbinfo_init(void)
{
    struct task_struct *node = current;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Starting module...\n");
    for(;node->pid != 1; node = node->parent)

    retrieve(node);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit pcbinfo_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning module...\n");
}
module_init(pcbinfo_init);
module_exit(pcbinfo_cleanup);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("arioglu");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Prints PCB info");
```

Makefile

```
  obj-m += modpcb.o
  all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
      dmesg | tail
      sudo insmod modpcb.ko
  clean:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

EDIT:Output. Error is gone by updating Makefile with insmod.

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/build M=/home/emre-ubuntu/Desktop/21202135/finalB modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic'
dmesg | tail
[  926.839624] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  926.839626] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  926.839628] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  926.839631] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  926.839633] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  926.839635] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  926.839637] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  926.840351] wlo1: associate with 04:18:d6:19:b7:61 (try 1/3)
[  926.843708] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 04:18:d6:19:b7:61 (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=21)
[  926.863483] wlo1: associated
sudo insmod modpcb.ko
```

Comment: I can't see any `modprobe` that load the compiled module....

Comment: I have edited the output. I added `sudo modprobe modpcb` to my Makefile. That return with error and then I used `insmod` instead still cannot load module.

Comment: Well, so your module is not loaded and nothing can be seen into `dsmeg`. What's the error?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it is an error. I expected to see what I have written in `printk`. You can see the latest output.

Comment: Did you drop the log level so info logs are visible?

Comment: I didn't change anything related with it.